# OS11 replacement for RadioInfo?

Tags: android-source, cellular-network, android-11

Is there a replacement for the RadioInfo that was removed as of OS11? (com.android.settings/.RadioInfo)
If not, where else can this information be found in UI? Or adb? (preferably without rooting the device)

Our team relies heavily on the use of the data in RadioInfo for QA testing, especially since it works on nearly all Android devices (rather than being OEM-dependent like engineering short codes).
It also offered ideal granularity in network selection, moreso than the basic Settings UI.

Also, why was it removed? I looked back about 11 months in logs and didn't see a single mention of it (though maybe I'm looking in the wrong place - if there's a comment on it somewhere, please do share the link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it just got moved.

**10 and earlier:**

```
com.android.settings/.RadioInfo
```

**as of 11:**

```
com.android.phone/.settings.RadioInfo
```